# How do I format time to UTC time zone?

Tags: scala

I have some date/time in a Date object; how can I format it to a string, so it represents appropriate date/time in **UTC** time zone?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm in central europe TZ. It is my code with joda-time:

```scala
scala> val myTz = DateTimeZone.getDefault()
myTz: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone = Europe/Warsaw

scala> val now = new Date()
now: java.util.Date = Tue Sep 23 12:06:05 CEST 2014

scala> val utcString = new DateTime(now).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toString()
utcString: String = 2014-09-23T10:06:05.302Z
```

Java 8:

Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_20).

```scala
scala>  import java.time._
import java.time._

scala> val utcZoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC")
utcZoneId: java.time.ZoneId = UTC

scala> val zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now
zonedDateTime: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 2014-09-24T09:45:31.165+02:00[Europe/Warsaw]

scala> val utcDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(utcZoneId)
utcDateTime: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 2014-09-24T07:45:31.165Z[UTC]
```

Comment: +1 for joda time. nscala-time is a nice wrapper library for joda time in scala

Comment: One less function call in the Java 8 case: `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"))`

Answer (score 7):

The solution without Joda Time:

```
val date = new Date()
val format = new SimpleDateFormat()
format.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(SimpleTimeZone.UTC_TIME, "UTC"))
val dateAsString = format.format(date)
```

Comment: Hmm, when I tried that, my local time being 15:31:38 (EST), the answer came out 08:31:38, when I would have expected 20:31:38 Z.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't 08:31:38 PM?

Comment: I see what happened, I used the 12 hour `hh` instead of the 24 hour `HH`.  Your code is fine, Daniel.

Comment: I'm glad you found the cause. The data format can sometimes be a little tricky :)